# Node.js app suddenly fails on local Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I have a very simple node.js app cloned from [this](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-todo) and the only addition is that it's connecting to an RDS instance.  It runs fine locally (OSX with `boot2docker`), and runs for a few minutes when I place it in a Docker container, and then all of a sudden, the page no longer renders and I get an empty response from the server.  The container is still running yet I'm getting a strange message in the logs.  Various files are below.

What am I missing here?

**Docker Run Command**
`docker run -p 49161:3000 -d <image name>`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM    centos:centos6

# Enable EPEL for Node.js
RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# Install Node.js and npm
# RUN yum -y install node
RUN yum install -y npm
RUN npm install -g express-generator@4
RUN npm install supervisor -g
RUN npm install pg --save
RUN npm install winston --save


# Bundle app source
COPY . /
# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

EXPOSE  3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Docker logs**

```
crashing child
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/1/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/1/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/1/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/1/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/1/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/1/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/5/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/5/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/5/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/5/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/5/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/5/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/6/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/6/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/6/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/6/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/6/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/6/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/8/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/8/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/8/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/8/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/8/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/8/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/9/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/9/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/9/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/9/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/9/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/9/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/7/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/7/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/7/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/7/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/7/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/1/task/7/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/11/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/11/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/11/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/11/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/11/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/11/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/13/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/13/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/13/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/13/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/13/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/13/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/10/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/10/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/10/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/10/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/10/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/10/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/14/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/14/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/14/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/14/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/14/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/14/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/16/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/16/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/16/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/16/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/16/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/16/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/15/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/15/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/15/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/15/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/15/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/10/task/15/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/10/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/10/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/10/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/10/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/10/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/10/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/11/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/11/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/11/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/11/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/11/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/11/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/13/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/13/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/13/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/13/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/13/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/13/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/14/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/14/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/14/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/14/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/14/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/14/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/15/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/15/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/15/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/15/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/15/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/15/root/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/16/cwd/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/16/cwd/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/16/cwd/proc/self/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/16/root/proc/1/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/16/root/proc/10/map_files
Error reading path: /proc/self/task/16/root/proc/self/map_files
```

**app.js File**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('./utils/logger');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./server/routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
//app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(require('morgan')({ "stream": logger.stream }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client', 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**Update 1**
Interesting...it looks like the container is no longer running after ~15 minutes.  It was running while I get the `Empty response` page, but now I can confirm the container is no longer running.  If re-execute the `docker run`, I do see the page load briefly, and the container up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this to help anyone else who runs into this.  Essentially, modifying my `Dockerfile` resolved this.  Apparently the memory in the original container was extremely high and was causing the container to crash.  I'm still not clear why that was happening, and I only used the majority of the original `Dockerfile` because that's what I found in the Docker examples.

**Revised Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:0.10-onbuild

RUN npm install supervisor -g
RUN npm install pg --save

EXPOSE 3000
```